# How to validate that foreign key value belongs to current user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

In my Rails 4 app I have `users` who can have many `companies` which in turn can have many `people`.

When a user creates a new person, how can I validate that he cannot possibly (through browser hacking) select *another* user's `company_id`?

I would like to deal with this at the model level, however this doesn't work:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :company

  validates :company_id, :inclusion => { :in => Company.where(:user_id => user_id) }

  ...

end
```

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass array of Company IDs to `in:` like this:

```
validates :company_id, :inclusion => { :in => Proc.new { |person| Company.where(:user_id => person.user_id).pluck(:id) } }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use proc:

```
 validates :company_id, :inclusion => { :in => proc { |record| Company.where(:user_id => record.user_id) } }
```

I hope the syntax is correct, i didn't check it :)